# Android Device cannot connect to apache server via "hostednetwork"

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, apache-http-server, android

I was created server in cmd "netsh wlan" etc. 
On first computer I have xampp with running apache server . 
When I connect other computer to my "hostednetwork", I can get the "localhost" from the first computer (from apache). This works fine.
But when I try do the same with my android phone, it doesn't work.
in cmd "show hostednetwork" i can see, that device is connect, but it doesn't work. 
How can i connect it ?